# Error al usar DateTime en C#

Tags: c#, datetime

Estoy trabajando en  visual c# y necesito pasar la fecha tal cual a una base de datos. 
También cuando  el  usuario guarde el  dato ingresado se le pregunte si  desea guardar más datos
Al darle si se limpie y el usuario pueda  escribir nuevamente en el  formulario

Mi código donde hago todo lo que acabo  de explicar es el  siguiente:

```
private void btnGuardar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {




        DialogResult result = new DialogResult();
        do {
            DateTime fecha = new DateTime();
            fecha = DateTime.Now;
            limpiarDatos();
            ObjDatos = new Datos(int.Parse(txtNumCuenta.Text), txtCarrera.Text, CbArea.SelectedItem.ToString(), int.Parse(txtEdad.Text), CbSexo.SelectedItem.ToString(), CBPadecimiento.SelectedItem.ToString(), TxtManejo.Text, CbAtendio.SelectedItem.ToString(), fecha);
            ObjDatos.guardar_datos();

            MessageBox.Show("Datos  guardados correctamente ¿guardar más datos?", "datos", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);
        } while (result == DialogResult.Yes);
    }

}
```

y el  error que obtengo  es este:

[image: Código de error]

MI clase Datos es esta:

```
namespace Captura
{



class Datos
{


    private int NumCuenta;
    private String carrera;
    private String area;
    private int edad;
    private String sexo;
    private String padecimiento;
    private String manejo;
    private String atendio;
    private String fecha;


    SqlConnection conexion;
    SqlCommand comando;
    SqlDataAdapter adaptador;
    String consulta;

    public Datos(int NumCuenta, String carrera, String area, int edad, String sexo, String padecimiento, String manejo, String atendio, String fecha)
    {
        this.NumCuenta = NumCuenta;
        this.carrera = carrera;
        this.area = area;
        this.edad = edad;
        this.sexo = sexo;
        this.padecimiento = padecimiento;
        this.manejo = manejo;
        this.atendio = atendio;
        this.fecha = fecha;
    }
    public Datos()
    {

    }

    public void setNumCuenta(int NumCuenta) { this.NumCuenta = NumCuenta; }
    public int getNumCuenta() { return NumCuenta; }
    public void setCarrera(String carrera) { this.carrera = carrera; }
    public String getCarrera() { return carrera; }
    public void setArea(String area) { this.area = area; }
    public String getArea() { return area; }
    public void setEdad( int edad) { this.edad = edad; }
    public int getEdad() { return edad; }
    public void setSexo(String sexo) { this.sexo = sexo; }
    public String getSexo() { return sexo; }
    public void setPadecimiento(String padecimiento) { this.padecimiento = padecimiento; }
    public String getPadecimiento() { return padecimiento; }
    public void setManejo(String manejo) { this.manejo = manejo; }
    public String getManejo() { return manejo; }
    public void setAtendio(String atendio) { this.atendio = atendio; }
    public String getAtendio() { return atendio; }
    public void setfecha( String fecha) { this.fecha = fecha; }
    public String getfecha() { return fecha; }

    public void conectar()
    {
        conexion = new SqlConnection("Data Source = ALO\\SQLEXPRESS; Initial Catalog = Medico; integrated security = true");
    }

    public void guardar_datos()
    {
        conectar();
        consulta = "insert into pacientes values(@num_cuenta,@carrera,@area,@edad,@sexo,@padecimiento,@manejo,@atendido,@fecha   )";
        comando = new SqlCommand(consulta, conexion);
        comando.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        comando.Parameters.Clear();
        comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@num_cuenta",getNumCuenta());
        comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@carrera", getCarrera());
        comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@area",getArea());
        comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@edad",getEdad());
        comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sexo",getSexo());
        comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@padecimiento",getPadecimiento());
        comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@manejo",getManejo());
        comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@atendido",getAtendio());
        comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fecha",getfecha());

        comando.Connection.Open();
        comando.ExecuteNonQuery();
        comando.Connection.Close();

    }

}




}
```

Comment: Los errores deben estar copiados en la pregunta. Las imagenes son dificiles de ver

Comment: Como es el objeto datos? el error te lo da al generar el objeto

Comment: estas seguro que el problema es la fecha? yo diria que el problema se presenta en int.Parse(txtNumCuenta.Text) o int.Parse(txtNumCuenta.Text) cuando quiere convertir a numerico un textox que quizas no tenga un numero valido

Comment: no se como asignas los datos a los combos, pero no deberias usar el CbArea.SelectedItem, se supone que si asignaste un DataSource deberias definir el ValueMember y por lo tanto usar el CbArea.SelectedValue

Comment: Te las contesto en orden:
1.- No es en mal plan pero.... ¿le has dado click para verla en tamaño mas grande?
2.-  practicamente es una clase donde mando todos mis textbox y mis combo para ser almacenados. Eso incluye la fecha. 
3.- 100% seguro que es la fecha. El error comenzó desde que puse el do-while 

4.- No he ocupado ningun  data Soruce para los combo.

Comment: Pues yo voy a repetir lo que siempre digo, ¿porqué usan textbox? el textbox es para texto. Quieres capturar fechas? usa un datetimepicker, ¿quieres capturar números? usa un numericupdown. Si aun así quieren usar textbox, usen Tryparse y mo parse.

Comment: Creo que tal vez en el constructor de Datos tu ultimo parametro espera un String y no un Datatime

Comment: @CristinaCarrascoAngulo he visto tu edicion y la he revertido. Si quieres dejarle comentarios al OP , no edites sus publicaciones, deja un comentario mejor. Un saludo

Comment: El error es bastante descriptivo. Lo que tratas de convertir no tiene el formato de fecha adecuado para poder ser convertido a DateTime.

Comment: Puedes mostrar la clase Datos porfavor

Answer (score 1):

1-  DateTime.Now no retorna un string, retorna un objeto DateTime y tu constructor de la clase Datos espera un String. Una lista completa con los formatos para el metodo toString puedes verlo en este enlace
http://www.geekzilla.co.uk/View00FF7904-B510-468C-A2C8-F859AA20581F.htm

```
String fecha = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd HH:mm:ss");
```

2- Para que el usuario pueda guardar mas datos debes eliminar el do...while y evaluar la respuesta del dialogo, borrar el formulario y dejar que el usuario siga el flujo normal, lo que tienes en tu código genera un loop que no permite al usuario guardar otros datos porque si responde 'Si' el while te lleva al inicio del loop, es decir, hay un error de lógica.

3- En C# no es necesario escribir los getters y setters como en java, puedes simplificarlo así:

```
private String carrera {get; set;}
```

Una muy buena explicación puedes revisarla aquï mismo en este enlace de la comunidad (en ingles)

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17881091/getter-and-setter-declaration-in-net

Comment: 1.- Eso lo solucioné conviertiendolo  a String como pones en el código
2.- Practicamente ponerle un if en  vez de  do- while??
3.-  lo sé pero no tengo  experiencia usando los get y set así como lo pones en  el  ejemplo, sino que  estoy acostumbrando a ponerlos tal cual.

4.- Esto  apenas se me ocurrió pero realmente no  sé ocupar "banderas":

En el mismo programa quiero poner un botón que diga limpiar datos (aunque con lo que me estás diciendo parece no ser ya  necesario, aún así lo pongo.)
Cuando el usuario de si al  dialogo se active ese botón para que pueda limpiar la interfaz